# Field Calculator, python- If else statement does not work

Tags: python, field, calculator

I try to convert different classes from a column into fewer classes in another column with the field calculator.

It works if I only use the expression field like this:

```
newfieldname = "Bla" if !Field! == 10 or !Field! == 12 else ("Blabla" if !Field! == 35 else 0)
```

but if I try to make a statement with the Pre Logic Script Code:

```
def reclass (a):
    if a == 10:
        return "Bla"
    else:
        return "Blabla"
```

Expression

```
newfieldname = reclass(!NRKART!)
```

it always shows me an error and I cannot understand why. I tried different '', other values and instead of "return" many other expression. Nothing worked so far.

Thanks.

Comment: *What* error? And what are those exclamation points doing in your code?